# Rails: searchkick gem and amazon ec2 instance, Faraday::ConnectionFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have created a amazon ec2 instance and successfully logged into the instance via `ssh`. And now I'm trying to to reindex a model from `rails c` with `Model.reindex`, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)
```

I have added all the tcp ports(80,22,5432,433,9200,9300) to the appropriate security groups.

Also I have edited the `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file with following information:

```
cluster.name: esonaws
bootstrap.mlockall: true
network.host: xxx.xx.xx.xx(this is the instance private ip)
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: xxx.xx.xx.xx(this is the instance private ip)
```

and then did a `sudo service elasticsearch restart`, the elasticsearch starts ok, but when I try to reindex again the same error pops up again.

btw when I do this inside the `ssh` `curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty` I get this:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

but if I use the private ip of the amazon ec2 instanceit works and returns all the cluster information.

```
curl http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_cluster/health?pretty^C
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here and how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch binds to `network.host`, so if you want to use `localhost` instead of the private ip, you need to use `network.host: _local_`.

[Relevant docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)